# Inventory Site Location availability in QuickBooks Desktop

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

We are using the field `Inventory Site Location` (Bin Location) that is part of the Advanced Inventory module in `QuickBooks Enterprise 14`.

We are able to use this on the Credit Memo & Inventory Transfers Add Requests but it fails for the other transactions types that are listed as supported in the QB SDK On Screen Reference.

I noted in the documentation that not all new SDK features are implemented in QuickBooks yet - is that the case here and if so is there any indication when they will be rolled out in QuickBooks Enterprise?

Comment: How can we answer your question if you don't tell us a) what error message you're getting and b) specifically what requests it's failing on?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting both the `site` and `sitelocation` and the the `site` you use is the parent of the `sitelocation`. I set these values by `listid` and was able to to create an invoice so it works with invoices.